# Google Drive API explorer redirects to reference page (no error message)

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to access the Google Cloud Console's API explorer, but I keep getting redirected to a reference page (no error message).

I have a previously working application, and in an effort to trace the issue I'm trying to access the API explorer.  The Google Drive API service is enabled, and when I click on it in the Enabled APIs & Services page, I'm taken to the Google Drive API Service Details page (Which appears to be as I would expect, with a Status of "Enabled").

[image: Link to Service]

[image: Link to Try In API Explorer]

When I then click on "Try in API Explorer" at the top of the page; it briefly loads:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/drive/v3/
And then, after about a half of a second, redirects to:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3?apix=true
(The Google Drive API reference page)

***Why is this happening?  How can I fix this?***

The same thing happens when I go to the list of services on the APIs Explorer Directory

[image]

I believe the script stopped working because someone rearranged the folder structure and my credentials somehow lost permission to access the folder listing.  I'm assuming this has something to do with this strange behaviour I'm experiencing.